# Using static import fields for constants?

Tags: java, code-standards, static-import

I have stumbled upon some existing code which is using static import for constants.

```
import static com.zee.SelfServiceConstants.ATTR_SEV;
import static com.zee.SelfServiceConstants.ATTR_SEV_CRITICAL;
```

and it is used in the same class as:

`propertyMap.put(ATTR_SEV, ATTR_SEV_CRITICAL);`

Is this a good practice?
Or the traditional way of referring to constants better?

```
propertyMap.put(SelfServiceConstants.ATTR_SEV, SelfServiceConstants.ATTR_SEV_CRITICAL);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. But there may be some readability.

From Java [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html).

> Used appropriately, static import can make your program more readable,
>   by removing the boilerplate of repetition of class names.

Comment: Agreed. But also from java doc: _If you overuse the static import feature, it can make your program unreadable and unmaintainable, polluting its namespace with all the static members you import._ My `class` namespace is polluted with so many of these static members import. :(

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you are using them much more than just once it's more convenient. I don't think that it either good or bad practice.